# Django: Saving a URL request parameter Into Form

Tags: python, django

I'm Using a Form to save data into it.

**models.py**

```
class presciptiontemplates(models.Model):
    templateid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    template = tinymce_models.HTMLField()
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    savedate = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    patientid = models.ForeignKey('Patient')
```

I'm Passing the parameter Patient Id From the URL.

```
url(r'^addprescription/(?P<patid>\d+)/$', views.viewtemplate
```

How do I save this parameter into form

**views.py**

```
def viewtemplate(request, patid):
    userid = patid
    form = templateform(request.POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            presciptiontemplates.patientid = userid
            form.save()
        return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = templateform()
    return render(request, 'presapp/prescription.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class templateform(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = presciptiontemplates
    fields = ['template', 'draft']
    widgets = {
    'template': TinyMCE(),
    'draft': forms.CheckboxInput()
    }
    labels = {
        "patientid": _("Patient ID"),
        }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ThatForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['template'].required = True
```

This gives me an error

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot insert
>   the value NULL into column 'patientid'

```
Django  1.10.4
Python  3.5.2
Windows 7
```

Comment: lots of things wrong with this question. Where is your modelform. What about the indentation. What on earth is presciptiontemplates which appears to be undefined?

Comment: Show the prescription.html and also tell us what is **presciptiontemplates** ?

Comment: Added modelform , presciptiontemplates is the model in which I Intend to save the Data from Rich text Editor

Comment: Add full traceback of the error. The error is coming from forms.py or from this line **presciptiontemplates.patientid = userid** ?

Comment: Error is Caused due to 
form.save()  In views.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line :

```
presciptiontemplates.patientid = userid
```

In your model, **patientid** is a foreign key to **Patient** Model, So it is expecting a Patient model object, and not the id of the patient as **patid**.
So firstly get the Patient object and then assign it to patientid,Like this :

```
def viewtemplate(request, patid):

    patient = Patient.object.get(id=patid)

    form = templateform(request.POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.patientid = patient
            form.save()
        return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = templateform()
    return render(request, 'presapp/prescription.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: It gives me an error 
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Patient'
Any suggestions

Comment: @RomilBahukhandi Error is in which line of this code ?

Comment: @RomilBahukhandi updating my answer. Try **form.patientid = patid** in the place of patient object.

Comment: The error trace-back is to form.save()
Im Using MSSQL As the backend using Pyodbc-azure , Can it be the Problem

Comment: Use this line also **form = form.save(commit=False)** Then the error should be gone.

Comment: Using 
form = form.save(commit=False)
form.patientid = patid   Did the trick , Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132362/discussion-between-prakhar-trivedi-and-romil-bahukhandi).

Comment: @RomilBahukhandi Come in chat please.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `templateform` is a model form.

You can use `commit=False` parameter in the save method and then save the object again with required parameters.

Short snippet to change as per your code

```
...
if request.method == "POST":
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.patientid = userid
        obj.save()
    return redirect('index')
else:
...
```

Answer (score 0):

To add userid value into new object you can use ModelForm.

Just make templateform inherited from ModelForm not Form class.

```
class templateform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = presciptiontemplates
```

now in view you can do following:

```
form = templateform(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.patientid = userid
    instance.save()
```